# Automatically connect to another database if failed in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I use Laravel 5.3. I have defined my connection to my DB in my env file.

I work with several MySQL server, if one is down, I want to automaticly use a 2nd connection.

I will use the filters I think and catch a PDOException.

But I want to know if Laravel have a better approach to do this, I would like to only use config / env.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using middlewares, you can try/catch the exceptions in your request and then switch your connection. Not sure if this will work with consoles or migration. Probably not.

Add this middleware in your application:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use DB;

class SwitchConnection
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            return $next($request);
        } catch (\Exception $e) { //Use a proper exception here, depending on which way/database you are connecting
            $this->switchConnection();
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    private function switchConnection()
    {
        //here get all connections from config that applies
        //@todo use a better way to get those db names
        $dbNames = ['conn1', 'conn2', 'conn3',];
        foreach($dbNames as $dbName) {
            try {
                \DB::connection($dbName)->getDatabaseName();
                \Config::set('database.default', $dbName);
                return;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add in your **Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'switchConnection' => \App\Http\Middleware\SwitchConnection::class,
```

Then in your **routes.php** you can do like this:

```
Route::group('middleware' => ['switchConnection']], function(){
.... //your routes go here
});
```

Comment: This a good approach ! This is what I wanted to do, by catching a PDO Exception. Thanks.